# How to get the data with a condition for other table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My query:

```
SELECT skill_code FROM TableSkills
```

I have tables `TableSkills` and `TableUsers`. How can I achieve `skill_code` data that only shows the `skill_code` if the user from `TableUsers` has at least "1"?

Expected result :

| skill_code |
| --- |
| Skill_1 |
| Skill_2 |
| Skill_3 |
| Skill_6 |

`TableSkills` :

| ID | skill_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Skill 1 |
| 2 | Skill 2 |
| 3 | Skill 3 |
| 4 | Skill 4 |
| 5 | Skill 5 |
| 6 | Skill 6 |

`TableUsers` :

| ID | User | Skill_1 | Skill_2 | Skill_3 | Skill_4 | Skill_5 | Skill_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | John | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Doe | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Jason | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | Kevin | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | Mike | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables with a `CASE` expression in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.skill_code
FROM TableSkills s INNER JOIN TableUsers u
ON 1 = CASE s.ID
         WHEN 1 THEN u.Skill_1
         WHEN 2 THEN u.Skill_2
         WHEN 3 THEN u.Skill_3
         WHEN 4 THEN u.Skill_4
         WHEN 5 THEN u.Skill_5
         WHEN 6 THEN u.Skill_6
       END;
```

Or, with `EXISTS`, which may perform better:

```
SELECT s.skill_code
FROM TableSkills s 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM TableUsers u
  WHERE 1 = CASE s.ID
              WHEN 1 THEN u.Skill_1
              WHEN 2 THEN u.Skill_2
              WHEN 3 THEN u.Skill_3
              WHEN 4 THEN u.Skill_4
              WHEN 5 THEN u.Skill_5
              WHEN 6 THEN u.Skill_6
            END
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q-AxvlmH).